# Mapping a stored procedure to a custom type in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns a couple of fields from a table that has many fields

I need to get this into a custom type in my model

I have added my entity and changed the function import to return objects of the new type but now I get a problem where the columns are not mapped